# Openstack Deployment

Tags: maas, openstack

These might be basic questions but they will help all the beginners to clear their concepts. So detailed answers would be really appreciated.

If we have 4 nodes how we can distribute the components on each node? 
Is it necessary that we deploy each components on every node ? E.g If we deploy neutron on node0 only, then how will other nodes have the functionality of networking ?

If we intall nova on 3 nodes then how will one remaining node perform the computer functions ? 
Can any one explain how these components are distributed ? 
What are the important factors we have to consider while distribution these components? and the logic behind them ? 
If we have neutron on one node and it goes down what will happen ?

What is the use of LXCs, cannot we install components independently without using LXCs ?

If have 4 servers in my setup (node0,1,2,3) with separate region controller and cluster controller in MAAS. I have boot strapped juju 2.0 on node0 . Now I want to deploy openstack on these 4 servers. Please help me out in the best possible deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenStack base](https://jujucharms.com/openstack-base/) bundle is a good reference for this type of deployment - it makes use of 4 physical machines to provide a single network node and 3 compute nodes, with the control plane charms for the cloud deployed in LXD containers across all four machines.

Additionally, Ceph storage is spread across all four machines, using the a secondary drive for the OSD (Object Storage Daemon).

The bundle is not an HA bundle - but that is possible todo by increasing the number of units in each service (ensuring they are spread across underlying physical services) in conjunction with the [hacluster](http://jujucharms.com/hacluster) charm

I'd like to see if we can also push the network node function into a LXD container - allowing a deployment to use all four machines as hypervisor nodes and maximising the use of the hardware.